# How to get NFC id in Android?

Tags: android, nfc

I need to get the NFC ID of the device.

AndroidManifest look like this:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

And to obtain the id, in the MainActivity (not in fragments), I added the fallowing code:

```
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i("MYTAG", "entered");
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        Log.i("MYTAG", "enter here also");
        Tag tag = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TAG: " + tag.getId().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

but this is not entering in the if statement. Does anyone have an idea?

I tried with different answers found from stackoverflow, but nothing changed.

Comment: From the comments below you seem to expect to get the ID of the device that is executing the above code. Is that right? Please clarify this in your question. If yes, please clarify what type of "ID" you want to get. The anti-collision identifier that other RFID/NFC reader devices see when you put your device on them? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you specified in the manifest intent-filter for TAG_DISCOVERED but in the code trying to match with ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.
I tested your code with TAG_DISCOVERED in onResume and it's ok (Nexus 5)

Comment: Did you mean if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {...}

Comment: Yes, but then you need to convert ID which is byte array into proper string representation because with toString() you get stuff like this [B@3a47c130

Comment: I do not want to read from some card or device. I want to get the id of my device, on which the app is installed. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by device id, but you can put necessary information into NDEF message and send it to another device in peer-to-peer mode http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#p2p

Answer (score 0):

I'd go `if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction()))` instead, but I can't test it as of lack of equipment^^

Comment: I tried to call  handleIntent(getIntent()); in main activity and wrote the fallowing code in the method:    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("MYTAG", "entered handleevent");
       if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
            Log.i("MYTAG", "enter here alsoasdada");
            Tag tag1 = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TAG: " + tag1.getId().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

Comment: Did you also call that in onResume()?

Comment: I removed it from onResume() and calling handleIntent from onCreate()